# Printing documents on HP printer very slow

Tags: windows, drivers, printer

I have a strange problem with HP drivers. I have configured a HP printer 2025dn with LAN connection, on 3 PCs, using the CD ROM of HP driver.

All works well, but sometimes for certain documents the time for printing is very slow and long. I observe during this situation, in task manager, a process called `rundll32.exe` loads CPU at 100%. If I kill that process the printer starts printing fast the document in the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the universal driver (PCL 5/6) from HP. Hope it solves your problem.

Here is the link, where you can select your windows version for download:

[HP Universal Print Driver Series for Windows](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=4157320&locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548)